# jquery: adding custom key value to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

whats wrong with this jquery code. it is not outputting anyting?

```
var imagesToLoad = [];

var name = 'hi';
var src = 'ho';

imagesToLoad[name] = src;

$.each(imagesToLoad, function(index, value) {
 alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

basically i want to add custom variables to my object after it has been created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript arrays don't support non numerical indexes. You probably want to use an object instead:

```
var imagesToLoad = {};
imagesToLoad.hi = 'ho';

$.each(imagesToLoad, function(index, value) {
 alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

Comment: thanks but actually the hi and ho are procedural so i dont know them in advance

Comment: Clamp: in that case, you can still use the square brackets for the property names on any object. imagesToLoad['hi'] === imagesToLoad.hi === imagesToLoad[name], where name = 'hi'

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [doc for $.each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - it accepts only callback function as parameter and it can iterate only over jQuery object